# symfony dynamic entity instantiation with php eval

Tags: php, symfony, model, doctrine

I have this set of entities that we call nomenclators, which basically have an id field and a text-based field. The CRUD operations for these entities are virtually the same, just that in some of them the text field is called state while in others is area... and so on.
Given that, I created this base Controller

```
class NomenclatorsController extends Controller
{

use ValidatorTrait;


protected function deleteENTITYAction(Request $req, $entityName)
{
    $id = $req->request->get('id');
    $spService = $this->get('spam_helper');
    $resp = $spService->deleteEntitySpam("AplicacionBaseBundle:$entityName", $id);
    if ($resp == false)
        return new JsonResponse("error.$entityName.stillreferenced", Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    return new JsonResponse('', Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED);
}


protected function listENTITYAction(Request $req, $entityName)
{
    $size = $req->query->get('limit');
    $page = $req->query->get('page');
    $spService = $this->get('spam_helper');
    $objectResp = $spService->allSpam("AplicacionBaseBundle:$entityName", $size, $page);
    $arrayResp = $spService->spamsToArray($objectResp);
    return new JsonResponse($arrayResp, Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED);

}


    protected function updateENTITYAction(Request $req, $entityName)
    {
        $id = $req->request->get('id');
        $entity = null;
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AplicacionBaseBundle:$entityName")->find($id);
        } else if (!is_numeric($id) || $id == null) {
//here comes the evil
            eval('$entity=new \\AplicacionBaseBundle\\Entity\\' . $entityName . '();');
            $entity->setEliminado(false);
            $entity->setEmpresa($this->getUser()->getEmpresa());

        }
        $this->populateEntity($req->request, $entity);
        $errors = $this->validate($entity);
        if ($errors)
            return new Response(json_encode($errors), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        $spamService = $this->get('spam_helper');
        $spamService->saveEntitySpam($entity);
    }


//Override in children
protected function populateEntity($req, $entity)
{
}



 }
```

So, each time I need to write a controller for one of these nomenclators I extend this NomenclatorsController and works like a charm.
The thing is in the updateENTITYAction I use eval for dynamic instantiation as you can see, but given all I have readed about how bad is eval I am confused now, and even when there is no user interaction in my case I want to know if there is a better way of doing this than eval and if there is any noticiable performance issue when using eval like this.

By the way I am working in a web json api with symfony and extend.js, which means no view is generated in the server,my controllers match a route and receive a sort of request params and do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past. Since you are extending a base class using specific classes for each entity you can instance your entity from the controller that extends NomenclatorsController.

If one of your entities is called Foo you will have a FooController that extends NomenclatorsController. Just overwrite updateENTITYAction and pass back needed variables.

An example:

```
<?php

use AplicacionBaseBundle\Entity\Foo as Item;

class FooController extends NomenclatorsController
{
    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing item entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     * @Template()
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Item $item
     * @return array|bool|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function updateENTITYAction(Request $request, Item $item)
    {
        return parent::updateENTITYAction($request, $item);
    }
}
```

This way you are sending directly the entity to NomenclatorController and you don't even need to know the entityName.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to specify I am working with Symfony via JSON Api with extend.js, nothing of twig or server-side generated views, so I dont get $item in my controllers but a sort of request parameters within the $request->request object. Anyway is really consistent your answer, I'll check FOSRestBundle and see if supports this. Upvoting

Answer (score -1):

Humm I'll me too advise you to **avoid** the `eval` function. It's slow and a bad practice.

What you want here is the [factory pattern](http://design-patterns.fr/fabrique),

You could define a service to create the entites for you

```
#app/config/services.yml
app.factory.nomenclators:
    class: YourNamespace\To\NomenclatorsFactory
```

And your factory might be like this

```
namespace YourNamespace\To;

use YourNamespace\To\Entity as Entites;

class NomenclatorsFactory {
    // Populate this array with all your Nomenclators class names with constants OR with reflection if you have many
    private $allowedNomemclators = [];

    /**
     * @param $entityName
     * @return NomenclatorsInterface|false
     */
    public function getEntity($entityName)
    {
        if(!is_string($entityName) || !in_array($entityName, $this->allowedNomemclators)) {
            // Throw exception or exit false
            return false;
        }

        return new $entityName;
    } 
}
```

Then you have to create the `NomenclatorsInterface` and define in it all the common methods between all your entities. Moreover define one more method getSomeGoodName, the job of this method is to return the good property (area or state)

With this structure your controller can only instances the Nomenclators entities and don't use anymore the eval evil method haha

Moreover you don't have to worry about about the state and area property

Ask if something isn't clear :D

I hope it help !

Comment: I think factory pattern is just a little overkill for this case, but anyway I like it. Thanks

Comment: How many entities do you have ? I don't understand the down vote

Comment: About 30 entities of type {id, name(or description or owner....) } I did'nt down vote you, I have no reputation for voting anyway. Besides as I toll you I do like your solution